# Navigate to a div page in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Purpose is to show a specific div page whom id is "triggers" when user clicks a button.
It is simple when there is "a" element like the following;

```
 <li data-icon="false"><a href="#triggers" id="report_triggers" data-transition="none" class="l10n-trig">Report on triggers</a>                </li>

  <div data-role="page" id="triggers">
  ...
  </div>
```

Is it possible to navigate to this div page from a javascript method ? 
I am using a trick here by putting an invisible "a" element

```
<a id="callTriggerPage" href="#triggers"><span>callTrigger Div</span></a>
```

And calling it from my function like this;

```
$('#callTriggerPage').find('span').trigger('click');
```

But I guess it should be simpler than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pagecontainer widget's change method:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#triggers", { transition: "slide" } );
```